# How to send data to <apex:include pageName

Tags: apex, include

I have an APEX class that collects data for a Quote record and then it is rendered on a Visualforce page, in PDF format, so that it can be printed.  Part of this process is to include a second document of terms and conditions, via an `<apex:include pageName="DLC_Bespoke_202010"/>`.  This process is working great, but a new requirement has been added.

Inside of the new page there are 3 areas that now need some custom data, from the quote object, printed into it.  My question, is there a way to send quote field information into this second page so that it can be rendered and printed?  This second page does not have its own controller, as it is just an include right now.  It also doesn't seem to see the data that is part of the original page, it is a blank space instead of the data that this APEX output field should have shown.  `<apex:outputField value="{!quoteDetail[0].AccountContact__r.Name}" />`.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't include any extra parameters using apex:include. This component is typically used to help render templates (e.g. a header and footer page). You should migrate your code to an apex:component instead, which would allow you to define apex:attribute values. You can reuse this component in other pages that also need it easily.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_templates_include.htm) supports this suggestion:

> Use the `<apex:include>` tag when you want to duplicate the entire content of another page without making any changes.

And:

> You should not use <`apex:include>` if you are only duplicating components. Custom components are better suited for reusable segments of code.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox,  I haven't ever done anything with components before and will look into them.  See if they will work for what I need here, and if I can get it working.  :)

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer as I was able to get Components working and it did the job in regards to the request I had.